# Is it permitted to use a user defined decorator inside an abstract class? Or, should it be used after inheritance?

Tags: python, abstract-class, python-decorators

For example, say I have a decorator I have defined called: `decorate`

```
def decorate(func):
  def inside_func(*args, **kwargs):
    # Do something
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  return inside_func
```

Next, let’s say I am writing an abstract class called Model

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Model(ABC):
  def __init__(self, value):
      self.value = value
      super().__init__()

  @abstractmethod
  @decorate # <-------------------- IS @decorate ALLOWED HERE?
  def do_something(self):
      pass
```

Or, should it be:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Model(ABC):
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value
    super().__init__()

  @abstractmethod
  def do_something(self):
    pass

# Inherit the base class
class DoAdd42(Model):
   @decorate # <----------------------- SHOULD @decorate BE HERE INSTEAD?
   def do_something(self):
     return self.value + 42
```

If both are allowed, is there a "best-practices" way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both allowed. Because `abstractmethod`, your `decorate` and `something` in class are all functions. You can print them to your console to verify.

```
In [2]: def decorate(func):
   ...:   def inside_func(*args, **kwargs):
   ...:     # Do something
   ...:     return func(*args, **kwargs)
   ...:   return inside_func
   ...:
In [7]: from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
   ...:
   ...: class Model(ABC):
   ...:   def __init__(self, value):
   ...:       self.value = value
   ...:       super().__init__()
   ...:
   ...:   @abstractmethod
   ...:   @decorate # <-------------------- IS @decorate ALLOWED HERE?
   ...:   def do_something(self):
   ...:       pass
   ...:   # even no self is valid for class in Python3+
   ...:   def whatever():
   ...:       print('fff')
   ...:

In [8]: print(abstractmethod)
<function abstractmethod at 0x100ff86a8>

In [9]: print(Model.do_something)
<function decorate.<locals>.inside_func at 0x1041031e0>

In [10]: print(Model.whatever)
<function Model.whatever at 0x103b48950>

In [11]: Model.whatever()
fff
```

I am not familiar with `abstractmethod`, so I don't know the best practices and more details about the rules of it. You can try to make your own judgment based on the information I give you, combined with your own understanding of `abstractmethod`.